# Replacing table rows with directives in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to create a table, but for each row I want a directive to be called that will create 1...N rows. The issue I am running into is getting AngularJS to replace the row with the directive.

Restrictions:

1. There must always be at least 1 item displayed, even if the data that is passed is null or empty. This restriction prevents me from using ng-repeat since upon null/empty it will not enter the loop as to be expected.
2. This data should be in a table. The information I want to display is in a tabular format, so I would like to keep it in a table. This limits me to what elements I can use. Since you can't have div elements inside a table

### Main HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-create-Rows />
</table>
```

### Create_Rows.HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>T</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
</tr>
```

### AngularJS

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ "xeditable" ]);

myApp.run([ 'editableOptions', function(editableOptions) {
    editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; // bootstrap3 theme. Can be also 'bs2', 'default'
} ]);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope',
                        function($scope) {} ]).directive('createRows', function() {
            return {
                transclude : true,
                templateUrl : 'Create_Rows.html'
            };
        });
</script>
```

### Actual output

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-create-rows="">
    <td>B</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>C</td>


    <td>T</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

### Wanted output

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
    <tr data-create-rows="">
         <td>B</td>
         <td>A</td>
         <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>T</td>
         <td>E</td>
         <td>F</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

---

### Update

Things I have tried

```
Replace | Transclude | Code                       | Results
----------------------------------------------------------------
false   | false      | <tr data-create-Rows />    | Only displays TDs
false   | false      | <tbody data-create-Rows /> | Multiple rows displayed
true    | false      | <tr data-create-Rows />    | Empty
true    | false      | <tbody data-create-Rows /> | Empty   
false   | true       | <tr data-create-Rows />    | Only displays TDs
false   | true       | <tbody data-create-Rows /> | Multiple rows displayed
true    | true       | <tr data-create-Rows />    | Empty
true    | true       | <tbody data-create-Rows /> | Empty
```

So using the tbody element appears to allow multiple rows to be created, but I am still wondering how do you replace an element with a directive, so that the original element is removed once the directive has been applied?

Comment: What have you achieved so far?

Comment: I've added my findings to the post.